# R: adding an histogram to a pairs plot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to add a small histogram of X4 somewhere in the upper part of the plot below. Can you help me?

```
X1 <- runif(100)
X2 <- runif(100)
X3 <- runif(100)
X4 <- runif(100)
pairs(~ X1 + X2 + X3, upper.panel=NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: `pairs` is just syntactic sugar. You can achieve this easily by creating the `layout` yourself instead of using `pairs`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems not possible using the pairs function directly unless using layout as suggested in the comments. A workaround would be to plot the correlation plots and histogram plot separately. If you liked the empty X1-X2-X3 diagonal that is presented by pairs you basically could mimic that using instead a grid of 3x3:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(X1, X2, xlab="X1", ylab="X2", main="")
hist(X4, main="")
plot(X1, X3, xlab="X1", ylab="X3", main="")
plot(X2, X3, xlab="X2", ylab="X3", main="")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
    h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
    breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
    y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
    rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col = "cyan", ...)
}
##[source][1]
```